# Metapost : input file within macros

Tags: macros, input, metapost

I like to have separate .mp files to organize my Metapost projects. But I'm facing this error message when I try to input file within a macro `File names can't appear within macros.` Even with this very clear message I'm wondering if there is a solution to call input files in a macro ? (package, extension, Metafun, Metafont, little hack, etc. ?)

```
def init =
    input var.mp
    draw (0,A)--(10,B)--(20,C);
enddef;

beginfig(1);

init;

endfig;
end.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `readfrom`:

```
string rf;
def init =
  forever:
    rf:=readfrom "var.mp";
    exitif rf=EOF;
    scantokens(rf);
  endfor
  closefrom "var.mp";
  draw (0,A)--(10,B)--(20,C);
enddef;

beginfig(1);

init;

endfig;
end.
```